# Interactive vs non-interactive shell environment with Ansible

Tags: bash, ubuntu-12.04, ansible, rbenv

I have a role that installs `rbenv`. Seems to work ok. However the environment is only loaded for an interactive session, so the rest of my playbook doesn't have access to the rbenv installed. This is Ubuntu 12.04. The `rbenv` role loads the environment via `/etc/profile.d` entry, which based on my reading should be loaded for non-interactive shells as well.

#### Non-interactive

```
> ssh mymachine 'echo $PATH'                                                                                                                                       
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

#### Interactive

Note that the first two entries reference `rbenv`:

```
> ssh mymachine
mymachine$: echo $PATH
/usr/local/rbenv/shims:/usr/local/rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

As a work around, I pass executable path to the `gem` module, but that doesn't seem like an optimal solution because other modules may rely an ruby version loaded and set by the interactive shell (rbenv):

```
gem: name=bundler state=present executable={{ gem_installed_path }}
```

Basically anything following `rbenv` role in my playbook that relies on correct ruby version (like the `gem` role) fails. What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: Assuming `/etc/profile.d` is like `.bash_profile` that's loaded for login shells (interactive or not). You could try forcing that.

Comment: Thanks Etan. I could do that, but I'd prefer not to tamper with the system if I can avoid it...

Comment: Hm? I meant force a login shell for the ansible execution environment. Otherwise you get to manually load it yourself in that environment (and that environment may be `/bin/sh` by default which may or may not support what you want correctly anyway).